# VBA auto return dates based on date range

Tags: vba, excel

I am having problems with my code

I have a start date in a worksheet called "Quotation" in C5
I have an end date in the same worksheet in C6

I then want the dates in-between to be displayed in another worksheet

The code I am using is:

```
Sub returnDates()
    Dim StartD As Date, EndD As Date
    Quotation.StartD = Cells(5, 3)
    Quotation.EndD = Cells(6, 3)
    For Row = 1 To EndD - StartD
        Cells(Row, 4) = StartD + Row - 1
    Next Row
End Sub
```

It returns with the following error 424 object required

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Quotation.StartD should be Worksheets("Quotation").StartD; same for Quotation.EndD

Comment: I think this would only work if StartD and EndD are declared at that top of your code as "Public StartD As Date". When I say at the top I mean above all subs and functions. then you can access them by name you don't need  to use quotation in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
Sub returnDates()
    Dim QuotationStartD As Date, QuotationStartD As Date
    QuotationStartD = Cells(5, 3)
    QuotationEndD = Cells(6, 3)
    For Row = 1 To (QuotationEndD - QuotationStartD)
        MsgBox QuotationStartD + Row - 1   ' put your sheet and cells
    Next Row
End Sub
```